# how to set patch value (update the nested value ) in array in array in angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I have one nested array like

```
permission": [
{
  "id": 2,
  "key": "creatBusinessPermission",
  "legend": "BusinessModule",
  "ischecked": false,
  "label": " Create Business Settings",
  "roles": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "key": "self",
      "ischecked": false
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "key": "selfrole",
      "ischecked": false
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "key": "other",
      "ischecked": false
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "key": "All",
      "ischecked": false
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "key": "editBusinessPermission",
  "legend": "BusinessModule",
  "ischecked": true,
  "label": " Edit Business Settings",
  "roles": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "key": "self",
      "ischecked": false
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "key": "selfrole",
      "ischecked": false
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "key": "other",
      "ischecked": false
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "key": "All",
      "ischecked": false
    }
  ]
}]
```

for above array I am using reactive forms,
After build a form I have one function for permission on onchange ,when that function is called that permission related ischecked and **self** ischecked change as true, I done with pesrmission is checked as true perfect, 
I am strugling to do to make is ** self ** ischecked as true,

This is my code

```
 (<FormArray>this.roleForm.controls['permission']).at(index).patchValue({
      ischecked : true
    }) This is works fine
```

Here I am not getting what to do

```
(<FormArray>this.roleForm.controls['permission']).at(index).get('roles').at(1)..patchValue({
      ischecked : true
    }) this code giving error, Probebly I did n't no how to do
```

Comment: '..' is actual typo or just typo in question?

Comment: it' s one scenario in my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
let x = (<FormArray>this.roleForm.controls['permission']).at(index).get('roles')
let y =   (<FormControl>x.controls[0])

y.patchValue({
        ischecked: true
      })
```